# turtle.bat: command not found (apache jena)

Tags: runtime-error, sparql, apache-jena

I was trying to check if a turtle file is valid and was also trying to produce results obatained from parsing. Could  you guys help me figure out why `turtle.bat` is not working.

```
MacBook-Pro:~ name$ export JENAROOT=/Users/name/Desktop
MacBook-Pro:~ name$ export PATH=$PATH:$JENAROOT/bin
MacBook-Pro:~ name$ turtle.bat q1.ttl
-bash: turtle.bat: command not found
```

Comment: 1.You have unpacked Jena directly on your desktop? 2. You're on a Mac. Why are you trying to execute a dos batch file? 3. It says "command not found" - which means it can't find the command. Check that the file is located in a dir on your path, and is executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `JENAROOT` should link to the root folder of the Jena distribution which is for sure not your desktop but the folder on your desktop that contains Jena, e.g. for me it's (Apache Jena 3.2.0) called `apache-jena-3.1.0`, thus it would be

   `export JENAROOT=/Users/name/Desktop/apache-jena-3.1.0`

   Is this really the correct path? Your username is "name"?
2. You're not using a Windows machine...it's simply

```sh
turtle q1.ttl
```

Comment: Only if you're in the appropriate directory...relative path -> Linux basics